# How to decide table relationship for ER diagram?

Tags: database, entity-relationship

[The table descriptionis here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFPsy.png)
Would you please help me to get the relatioship among the tables? PK and FKs are given but cannot link which table are related to which.. Help appreciated..

Comment: please upload image directly here. dropbox location does not work.

Comment: @VenkataramanR - this is the OP's first visit to the site so they lack the rep to gain the privileges required to embed images.

Comment: Again, no external files please. Notice in the editing tools on Stack Overflow you can embed an image. A dialog box appears into which you can drag your local image file. The file is uploaded to imgur.com, and auto-displayed on this page.

Comment: @mdfahd - Please read this post here on [embedded images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post). You won't be able to embed it yourself but you can post **an accessible link** which will allow somebody else to embed it. If you don't do this your question will get closed and you won't get an answer.

Comment: "Table relationships" are a misconception. Relationships in the ER model are represented by tables themselves.